# Nested template class argument deduction differences between compilers

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

The below example compiles fine in both [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/b89cfeKK5) and [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/x8va1hK6W):

```
template <typename>
struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    struct Bar {
        Bar(T val): 
            val_(val) 
        {             
        }

        T val_;
    };
};

auto func() {
    return Foo<int>::Bar(3);
}
```

In [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/7ae4PMx8q) there seems to be a need for an extra deduction guide, for it to compile:

```
template <typename>
struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    struct Bar {
        Bar(T val): 
            val_(val) 
        {             
        }

        T val_;
    };

    template <typename T>
    Bar(T) -> Bar<T>; // deduction guide
};

auto func() {
    return Foo<int>::Bar(3);
}
```

Is there a rationale behind this extra requirement in clang? Or is it just a difference in the interpretation of something that's unclear in the standard to begin with?

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33489#c9

Comment: Looks like the issue is tracked on the standard side by [CWG2471](https://wg21.link/cwg2471).

Comment: @bogdan The example in CWG2471 seems similar to mine. Like mine, it also compiles fine in both [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/Tjqzfr68d "link to example on godbolt") and [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/q6va1WbqP "link to example on godbolt"), while [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/z8brer53j "link to example on godbolt") gets the same result only with an added deduction guide `template <typename U> N(T, U) -> N<U>`.

Comment: As for the discussion of deducing the outer type T from the constructor of the inner struct, I'm inclined to think that this is not an option.

Comment: Annoyingly, as far as I can tell, clang is conformant to the standard text in its current form, and the others aren't. About deducing the outer template argument, yeah, I don't see how that is relevant to your case, or to the example in the CWG issue description, for that matter; I don't think that's the main issue in these cases. The comment in clang's bug tracker explains the problem much better. I guess more details about why the current standard wording doesn't make this work could go into an answer, if you're interested in a more elaborate explanation. cc @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica

Comment: No, I just thought I'd mention it, if it was not already tracked, which it seems as it is. Thanks!

Comment: (That being said, it would be interesting to see a practical example where the implicit deduction guides in gcc and msvc can pose a problem.)